# Express: request.body is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

SOLVED: I wasn't placing middleware before the route. It's fixed now:

```
// place middleware before route
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', bookRouter);
```

I'm using Postman to post this:

```
{
    "title": "Biography of Malcolm X",
    "author": "Alex Haley",
    "genre": "Non-Fiction"
}
```

The result is 200 but I'm only getting back the default values I sent in my Model, plus a generated ID:

```
{
    "read": false,
    "_id": "6012c00012491b0b9e53f09b"
}
```

Here's my Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const bookModel = new Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  author: { type: String },
  genre: { type: String },
  read: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookModel);
```

In my index.js file I'm not using *body-parser* because it's deprecated. Here's what I have:

```
const app = express();
const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookAPI', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
app.use(express.json());
```

This is the recommended way, right? But when I log my POST handler I get *undefined*. Here's the handler:

```
.post((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const book = new Book(req.body);
    res.json(book);
```

})

This isn't right? From all the docs I've read this is correct. What am I missing?

Here are the headers from Postman:

[image]

And here's the request:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this middleware

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Comment: or app.use(express.json()) if the enctype is ;'json'. You have to parse the payload you send in your requests to populate req.body. Otherwise the req.body is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added screenshots of the Postman request/response. The Content-type header is set to JSON but adding app.use(express.json()) isn't working.